# MYSQL Retrieving 1715 rows then it stops

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Having some problems with getting rows were it gets stuck. Its a strange number. Somewhere around 1715 it hangs. So when using LIMIT 0,1715 gives me the result in 2-3 sec. But using LIMIT 0,1716 just hangs it, no error nothing. The browser just spins and spins. Very strange! I have look at the output were it locks at 1715. The last row until it stops. Cannot se anything wrong with it.

Here is my SQL Query:

```
      SELECT a1.*
    , t2.`name` AS project_name
    , t2.`id` AS project_id   
    , u2.`fname` AS fname
    , u2.`lname` AS lname
    , u2.`color` AS color 
    , u2.`id` AS user_id 
    , u3.`fname` AS creatorfname
    , u3.`lname` AS creatorlname

    FROM `activities` AS a1 
    LEFT JOIN `projects` AS t2 ON a1.`projectid`=t2.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `users` AS u2 ON a1.`userid`=u2.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `users` AS u3 ON a1.`creatorid`=u3.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `organisations` AS o1 ON u2.`orgid`=o1.`id` WHERE
      o1.`id`=:orgid AND a1.`active`=1 AND a1.`userid`=:userid  ORDER BY  
      a1.`date` DESC LIMIT 0,1716
```

Using this do NOT work, using LIMIT 0,1715 does. But if i do 1715,10 it gives me hits.

What can this be? Thank you!

Comment: Look to your log files.... initial guess, out of memory

Comment: Share you sql query if possible.

Comment: check this the row with "LIMIT 1715,1" and check how much size this contains...

Comment: Using for example LIMIT 1715,10 gives me results without problems.

Comment: Does this run if you run it in phpMyAdmin for example? Also check the `php error log` for memory exausted messages

Comment: If I try SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE `userid`=11 LIMIT 0,1715 it says loading but nothing happens. If I use SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE `userid`=11 LIMIT 0,900 same there. But when accessing php directly works up to LIMIT 0,1715.

Comment: Looked at the error log no problems just basic php errors there.

Comment: Bump ;) I cannot figure this out. Other computers have no problem listing more than 1716 rows. Could there be some settings in Chrome. Please help :)